# How can I set icon for Mac OS X Bundle?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have try to set icon for my App in the xCode. 
In the info.plist I wrote:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon</string>
```

icon is icon.icns file 57X57 in the resources.

But finally bundle does not contain an icon.
When I press about my app Item in the menu bar an about window appears with my icon.

What's wrong?

Please help.

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `<string>icon.icns</string>`

EDIT:  An icns file is not a simple png file; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image).  You can use `Icon Composer.app` included in Apple's Xcode Developer Tools (`/Developer/Utilities`). to convert your icon file to icns format; just drag the file into the window area.

Comment: It does not work :(
May be icon.icns is incorrect. I have rename this file from png extension. Actually icon.icns is png image...